# pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32

Tags: linux-mint, usbserial

I'm trying to access the data stream from my Solar inverter. The inverter device is recognised in lsusb (Bus 002 Device 007) but it is disconnected as seen from dmesg. Can anyone help me with this, please?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:58c1 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0000:3825  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

$ dmesg|grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[  460.175426] usb 2-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  478.375365] pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[  478.375732] pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[  478.672989] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_set_control_lines - failed: -19
[  478.673006] pl2303 ttyUSB0: error sending break = -19
[  478.673382] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  479.442249] usb 2-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  480.719091] pl2303 ttyUSB1: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
```

You may ask about this information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux kumar54-Laptop-home 4.15.0-101-generic #102~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 11:44:23 UTC 2020 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Release:    18.3
Codename:   sylvia
```